# Regular Expressions: Numeric Value before Occurrence PHP

Tags: php, regex

Given the string:

```
100,000 this is some text 12,000 this is text I want to match.
```

I need a regular expression that matches *12,000* based on matching

```
text I want to match
```

So, we can get a position with:

```
strpos($haystack, 'text I want to match');
```

Then, I guess we could use a regular expression to look backwards:

But, this is where I need help.

Comment: Wouldn't you match a number followed by what you want to match? Like `([\d,]+) this is text I want to match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the digits will always precede the based context you want to match ...

```
preg_match('/([\d,]+)\D*text I want to match/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple:

```
/ ([0-9,]+) this is text I want to match\.$/
```

Demo:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b288ca9a322c7a5b54c6490334540ab142b6a979

Comment: This was a great quick answer but a more complete answer that allowed more of the flexibility I needed was offered.

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution:**

```
$re = "/([\\d,]+)(?=\\D*text I want to match)/";
$str = "100,000 this is some text 12,000 this is text I want to match.";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ3zN5/1)